# Write to variable outside of block in objective c

Tags: objective-c, block

I can't access variables outside the block (apparently). I can't return a value from the block it seems. I can't believe using properties of the class is the best practice here...

```objectivec
// Return true when failed
- (bool)myMethod:(XCUIElement *)element {
    bool fail = false;
    [self waitWithTimeout:timeout
                  handler:^(NSError *_Nullable error){
                  if (error != nil) {
                    // How do I assign to fail here?
                    fail = true;
                   }
    }
  return fail;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post your code? I just submitted an answer, but reading over the question again, I'm not completely sure if it addresses your question.

Comment: You should absolutely learn the '__block' keyword and the 'weak self' pattern.  However, based on how I understand your question, you might be able to get away with something fairly simple.  Blocks will capture locals.  You can't reassign a local without __block, however you can change an existing object.  do:   NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string]; (or is it stringWithString: @""?)  Outside the block.  Then in the block ^{ [str appendString: @"whatever! "]; }   This should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in accessing properties in a block, but you have to be careful.

by default blocks capture variables strongly. if the class now holds the block, you get an retain cycle.

To avoid this, you can create a weak variable of self. in the block you than create a (default) strong variable to avoid, that the object self will be released while processing the block

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.testBlock = ^(NSInteger itemIndex) {
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if(strongSelf){
         strongSelf.foo = ....;
    }
};
```

if you want to write to a variable from the surrounding scope, you use `__block`.

```
__block NSUInteger foundIndex = NSNotFound;

[array enumerateObjectsUsingComparator:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, *BOOL stop){
    if([obj ....]){
        foundIndex = idx;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is local to the block you declare it with `__block`:

```
__block NSString *blockString = @"Blocks are cool";
```

Generally, you should be able to access them without `__block`, but you need it if you want to change the value of the variable.